# FtpInboundFileSynchronizer - setting filter not working as expected

Tags: java, spring

I have a sub-method that builds my FtpInboundFileSynchronizer object. (from a factory object generated out of scope)

```
private FtpInboundFileSynchronizer createFtpInboundFileSynchronizer(SessionFactory<FTPFile> factory) {
        var synchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(factory);
        CompositeFileListFilter filter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
        filter.addFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("filename1.txt"));
        filter.addFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("filename2.txt"));
        synchronizer.setFilter(filter);
        synchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(ftpConfiguration.getPath());
        synchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        return synchronizer;
    }
```

However, in this case, I get no files. If I remove one of the FTPSimplePAtternFileListFilter instances, it correctly retrieves that one filename from the FTP server.

The aim is to only download a predefined list of full file names, so both name and extension. 
I cannot seem to wrap my head around how to do this. Anyone able to help?

Comment: The `CompositeFileListFilter` is and and filter. All filters need to return `true` to make it match. In your case there will always be one which won't return `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractDirectoryAwareFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;

/**
 * Filter to accept specific file name list.
 */
public class MultiPatternFileListFilter extends AbstractDirectoryAwareFileListFilter<FTPFile> {

    private final AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();
    private String[] patterns;

    public MultiPatternFileListFilter(String... patterns) {
        this.patterns = patterns;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(FTPFile file) {
        return alwaysAccept(file) || (file != null && this.matchesAnyPattern(file));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isDirectory(FTPFile file) {
        return false;
    }

    protected String getFilename(FTPFile file) {
        return (file != null) ? file.getName() : null;
    }

    private boolean matchesAnyPattern(FTPFile file) {
        return Arrays.stream(patterns).anyMatch(pattern -> this.matcher.match(pattern, this.getFilename(file)));
    }
}
```

This solved my problem.